# marionette control from backbone controls

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I want to create mariontte control that consists of three backbone controls. First is Date Picker, second is numeric stepper and the third one is again Date Picker. The idea is that first date is the initial date and numeric stepper adds days and the result is shown in second Date Picker. Anyway I don't know how to create Marionette view when not all child items are the same. How should I approach this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you can create a compositeview(or even layout can work) having three divs and render three different itemviews in the three divs by explicitly adding the el of the itemViews in the divs

> e.g. if following is your compositeview template

```
<div id="first-datepicker"></div>
<div id="numeric-stepper"></div>
<div id="second-datepicker"></div>
```

> Then in your compositeView JS you can render itemviews as follows

```
ui:{
    firstDatepicker: "#first-datepicker",
    numericStepper: "#numeric-stepper",
    secondDatepicker: "#second-datepicker"
},
onRender: function(){
    this.ui.firstDatepicker.html(new DatePickerView().render().el);
    this.ui.numericStepper.html(new NumericStepperView().render().el);
    this.ui.firstDatepicker.html(new DatePickerView().render().el);
}
```

But in case of layout you do not need to explicitly render the view, you can simply use show method of layout as

```
regions:{
    firstDatepickerRegion: "#first-datepicker",
    numericStepperRegion: "#numeric-stepper",
    secondDatepickerRegion: "#second-datepicker"
},
onRender: function(){
    this.firstDatepickerRegion.show(new DatePickerView());
    this.numericStepperRegion.show(new NumericStepperView());
    this.secondDatepickerRegion.show(new DatePickerView());
}
```